# how to use scalate with scalatra

Tags: scala, scalate

Hi Iam developing a application with Scalatra.I would like to use scalate 
to render the pages using the template. Are there any blogs or pointers to combine 
scaml and scala code.

Answer (score 0):

http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/index.html
here